# Distance percentage of a point relative to a line end in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, linear-referencing

I have a Polyline and a Points shapefile. I need to create a new Field in the Points shapefile with the distance percentage from the coordinate-priority of the line they belong to. The coordinate priority is the lowest-rightmost end of each line feature. I'm working with ArcGIS 10.2.2 (Advanced License). Here's an example:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something not right with two upper points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a unique ID for the lines
- Create Routes from the lines - double check your line directions are the same
- Locate features along routes (your points)
- Divide the distance along the line by line length x 100%

Comment: I tried to do this before asking this question, but since my "route" was not projected, it was giving me weird "Measure" values (in decimal degrees). I projected it, and then I realized that it was giving me the actual length from the priority coordinate to the point... Anyway, thanks a lot!